# How do I return a string based on two boolean values?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I need to create a program with the following logic:

- If x is true, return the string "Red"
- If y is false, return the string "Yellow"
- If X is true  and y is false, return the string "Blue"
- Otherwise, return the string "Purple.

```js
let x = true;
let y = false;

function logicalColors(x,y) {
}
```

How do I implement this function? Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
function logicalColors(x,y){
  if (x == ture){
    return "Red"
  } else if (!y == false) {
    return "Yellow"
  } else if (x && !y) {
    return "Blue"
  } else {
    return "Purple"
  }
}

console.log(logicalColors);
```

Comment: Your question should be tagged with the language you are using.

Comment: I coped your code from your self-answer to your question because it should have been an edit. You have a typo in your code: `if (x == ture)` should be `if (x == true)`. Also, your second condition is `if (!y == false)` while the problem statement says "If y is false", so you'll get the wrong result there.

Comment: As far as random tips go you can just do `if(x)` instead of `if(x==true)`. You are already doing that here...`else if (x && !y)`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want if-else ladder. Then i tried little cleaner way

```
function logicalColors(x,y) {
  if (x) {
    if (!y) {
      return 'blue'
    }
    return 'red'
  }
  
  if (!y) {
    return 'yellow';
  }

  return 'purple';
 }
```